# Implicit type conversion and time measurement

Tags: c++

I'm implementing a game loop in `c++` using the `timeGetTime` function like below:

```
    // ...
    DWORD oldtime = 0, newtime = 0, delta = 0;
    //...
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {               
            exit(0);
        }

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    }

    delta = newtime - oldtime;      

    while (delta >= MS_PER_UPDATE) {

        //update();
        delta -= MS_PER_UPDATE;
        g_loopCnt++;
    }
    //render();
    // ...
```

I know that the value returned by the `timeGetTime` function wraps around to 0 every 2^32 milliseconds, which is about 49.71 days as the official doc says. So is it possible (however, it is very unlikely) that the delta will be a negative number (when the `newtime` will pass the "magic" 2^32 milliseconds barrier). Lets take for an example VERY unlikely but theoretically possible case:

> `newtime` == 304(dec)
> `oldtime` == 0x7FFFF82F (2147481647 dec)

when the game is running longer then these 49.71 days. We'll get:

```
delta = 304(dec) - 2147481647(dec) == -2147481343(dec signed!);     
...
    while (-2147481343 >= MS_PER_UPDATE) {...}
```

So there is of course a resulting a negative numer (`-2147481343`) so on the fiest look it won't work here. BUT the compiler will make here an implicit conversion from signed to unsigned resulting in:

```
while (2147485952 >= MS_PER_UPDATE) {...}
```

and finally the code WILL work! (thanks to this implicit conversion)
And here is my question. Is it ok/safe to let the code be simple like that and just rely on the implicit conversion made automatically OR maybe I have to take care of the "wrap around" problem myself doing some extra checking/coding?

P.S

If I cannot count on that automatically implicit conversion is it a good solution to just change the operand order when there is about to be an negative delta like below?:

```
if(newtime < oldtime)
    delta = oldtime - newtime;
```

Comment: What are the types of `delta`, `oldtime`, `newtime` and `MS_PER_UPDATE`?

Comment: @YurkoFlisk I've just added the type definitions. (it's DWORD as the `timeGetTime` also returns a `DWORD` value)

Comment: `DWORD` is unsigned and will always wrap around. So do not use e.g. `if (newtime > oldtime + waittime)`, as `newtime` could have been wrapped around (the left side of the comparison would be small and stay small for a long time and the right side could be near the max). Change such conditions to `if (newtime - oldtime > waittime)`. You solved it by calculating a `delta`, which gives the second solution (`delta = newtime - oldtime; if (delta > waittime)`). But be careful, when running your game in a paused debugger or on a very busy PC, there could be more than 50 days between your events ;-)

Comment: @Sebastian Sorry friend but i think You've deviated a little bit from what I've asked. All I'd like to know is I'm right that thanks to the automatic implicit conversion when the delta turns to be a negative number the compiler automatically converts it from signed to unsigned thus making the condition still working(look above to the details i the main question). Thx.

Comment: There are no negative or signed numbers involved. DWORDS wrap around. No conversion happens. That is why you have to think and plan, where the wrap around can happen.